# Application error with MyFaces 1.2: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application

Tags: jsf, tomcat, myfaces

For my app I'm using **Tomcat 6.0.x** and **Mojarra 1.2_04** JSF implementation. 
It works fine, just I would like to switch now to **MyFaces 1.2_10** impl of JSF.

During the deployment of my app a get the following error:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/myApp]] StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:106)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:137)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.init(MyFacesServlet.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4371)
...
```

Here is part of my web.xml configuration:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <!-- <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class> -->
        <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    ...
    <listener>
         <listener- class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Has anyone experienced similar error, and what should I do i order to fix it? Thanx!

**EDIT:**

I was able to fix the problem. Since I am using delegator for **FacesServlet**, it turned out that this delegator was causing the problem. 
All I needed to do is to make this class implement **DelegatedFacesServlet**, and I've removed *org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener*. Here is my web.xml now:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <!-- <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class> -->
        <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet Delegator</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.myapp.web.FacesServletDelegator</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet Delegator</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and here is **FacesServletDelegator**

```
public class PLMFacesServlet extends HttpServlet implements DelegatedFacesServlet {

    private MyFacesServlet delegate;

    public final void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
        delegate = new MyFacesServlet();
        delegate.init(servletConfig);
    }

    public final void destroy() {
        delegate.destroy();
    }

    public final ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        return delegate.getServletConfig();
    }

    public final String getServletInfo() {
        return delegate.getServletInfo();
    }

    public final void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {

       try {
           delegate.service(request, response);
       } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
    // some other code...
}
```

**EDIT 2**:

Following **BalusC** advice, I've edited my *web.xml* a bit, here is the final version:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet Delegator</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.web.FacesServletDelegator</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet Delegator</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I don't do MyFaces, but I am in fact *very* surprised that you apparently need to outcomment the JSF 2.0 API specified `<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>` and use the MyFaces specific one. This would mean that MyFaces is not compatible with JSF 2.0 API. Or was this just your ignorance? Undo that outcomment and get rid of MyFaces impl specific declarations and retry. Does it work?

Comment: It is working. Thanx BalusC for pointing this out. When I was searching what might be the cause of the initial problem, I've probably made this change also. I'll edit my question following your advice...

Comment: Just for reply an earlier comment and make it clear, MyFaces Core is 100% compatible with JSF 2.0 API, because some tests done before each release check that. Override the default standard FacesServlet and use a delegate one is implementation specific, that means, it is a hack "outside" the spec. There are some valid use cases to do that, but as a "best practice" you should not rely on that. If you have more questions about MyFaces, you can additionally ask on [MyFaces users and dev mailing lists](http://myfaces.apache.org/mail-lists.html)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the removal of the following line from my web.xml:

```
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

...was what made the error disappear.

(Was fixing up a pure Tomcat 7 to work with JSF.)